# Where are the short-circuiting operators in ActionScript/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, operators, short-circuiting

Like VB has operators [AndAlso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz(VS.80).aspx) and [OrElse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2(VS.71).aspx), that perform **short-circuiting** logical conjunction, where can equivalent operators be found in JS / AS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal && and || operators do short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, JS and AS use short-circuiting by default.

Defaults might be a good example:

```
var value = input || false;  // defaults: non-zero `input` or `false`
```

Ternary is another -- only the block needed is executed:

```
return typeof(value) == 'string' ? value.substr(0, 2) : '';
```

Comment: The ternary is an evil eveeeel statement that should be avoided at all costs imo.  Just too freaking hard to read!  I've lost count of the number of bugs I've found in code because someone thought they'd be cute and use the ternary...

Comment: i disagree. ternary operators are straightforward, simple, and concise.